# "Export" SQL Tuning Profile to another instance?

Tags: oracle

I left work Friday with a long running SQL Tuning Advisor session running from Grid Control in Oracle, on one of our development instances. Some of these sessions take over 4 hours to run, so I prefer to run them on clones of production rather than the production box. My problem is I would like to implement the profiles at times on the production instance. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this page:

[**SQL Profiles - Collection of Information About SQL Profiles**](http://ba6.us/book/export/html/117)

The section *"Transporting SQL Profiles Between Databases"* describes a procedure in seven steps:

1. Create a staging table to store the SQL Profiles
2. Pack the SQL Profiles to the staging table
3. Export the table using Datapump or Export/Import
4. Execute the query in another database without SQL Profiles
5. Import the SQL Profiles to the database
6. Unpack the SQL Profiles
7. Check the SQL Profiles

The detailed steps are in the page I linked to.

*I hope this helps.*

---

**Edit:** Here is another nice link as submitted by Serverfault user [David Mann](https://serverfault.com/users/24021): [**SQL Profiles**](http://ba6.us/node/117).

Comment: +1, thanks for the info, will try when I get back to work...

Comment: Perfecto! Everything works as described. The only hiccup I had was determining the name of the sql profile, which grid control does a good job of hiding from you. I finally found it in SYS.DBA_SQL_PROFILES. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Thank you for coming back and providing the extra information.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, a prettier version of the pages are here: http://ba6.us/node/117 . I threw it up on my site because I needed a single place to reference the info and was tired of diving into the docs (and google) every time I needed to move profiles around. One day I will prettify it a little more and smooth some of the rough edges. But glad someone is getting use out of it.